# Multiple independent blob link's on a static Rails web UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, download

I am creating a web page for a project using Ruby on Rails that will run scripts selected by a user and will build elements on the bottom of the page using JavaScript to display the results.  Each result element consists of a Bootstrap collapsible presentation area containing the results.  I am implementing a download link at the bottom of each presentation block, which just saves all the text inside as a .txt file to be downloaded.  I am using JavaScript blob's to achieve this, but have run into an issue.  I need to have a limitless number of links to hold data to be downloaded, but every time a new link is made the previous one stops working for downloads.  I have tried saving the blob links into an array and returning resulting link from that, to no avail.  The function that builds the blobs is as follows:

```
var textFile = null,
makeTextFile = function(text){
  data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

  if(textFile !== null) { window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile); }
  textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return textFile;
};
```

I could handle the downloads using Ruby on Rails "send_file", but that requires the web page to reload which will lose all the other results.  The code that builds the result elements is as follows:

```
if(document.getElementById("dig").checked == true)
{
  $('#dig_wait_img').addClass('hidden');
  $('#dig_loading_img').removeClass('hidden');
  results = $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/console/discovery/dig",
    data: { domain_name : domainInput },
    success: function(data) {
      resultArr.push(data["value"]);
      $('#dig_loading_img').addClass('hidden');
      $('#dig_check_img').removeClass('hidden');
      $("#results")
      .append(
        $("<div class=\"panel panel-default\">")
        .append(
          $("<h4 class=\"panel-title\">")
          .append(
            $("<a data-toggle=\"collapse\" href=\"#collapse" + count + "\">DIG - " + domainInput + "</a>")
          )
        )
        .append(
          $("</h4>")
        )
        .append(
          $("</div>")
        )
        .append(
          $("<div id=\"collapse" + count + "\" class=\"panel-collapse collapse\">")
          .append(
            $("<pre><div class=\"panel-body\" id=\"body" + count + "\">" + data["value"] + "</div><a id=\"" + count + "\" href=\"" + makeTextFile(data["value"]) + "\" download=\"" + data["file"] + "\">Download</a><div class=\"panel-footer\"></div></pre>")
          )
        )
        .append(
          $("</div>")
        )
        .append(
          $("</div>")
        )
      );
      count++;
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
      $('#dig_loading_img').addClass('hidden');
      $('#dig_x_img').removeClass('hidden');
    },
  });
}
```

If anyone has any experience with handling multiple download links made with blob on a static web page, or if you just have any suggestions in general, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh the joys of being tired... After taking a step back and thinking maybe it's not how I'm approaching the problem, but something I assumed was required.  The actual problem didn't reside in how I was trying to store the blob links, but the fact that the textFile variable doesn't get reset to null, and I check if the file is not null and revoke the link if so.  Removing the if statement in the makeTextFile function solved the problem!